# E ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'post'

Tags: python-3.x

desde hace un tiempo tengo la siguiente estructura de archivos

```
/dev
  /post.py
  /main.py
```

quiero importar a post dentro de main.py. ya que en post.py tengo una única función "send" y la estoy importando de la siguiente manera

```
from post import send
```

y al ejecutar individualmente el archivo main.py todo sale OK, pero al ejecutarlo con pytest sale el siguiente error:

```
ERROR  - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'post'
```

si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradezco mucho porque ya no sé donde más buscar.

Comment: Ese pytest, lo ejecutas desde cmd?

Comment: si, señor y si lo importo de la siguiente manera from .post import send al ejecutar el pytest todo Ok pero al correr el scrip no funciona

Comment: Desde donde y con que corres el script?